# Как уменьшить код?

Tags: python

```
dva = 2
minus = -1
a1 = ''
a2 = ''
a3 = ''
a4 = ''
a5 = ''
a6 = ''
a7 = ''
a8 = ''
a9 = ''

print('День:')
den = input()
x = [int(a) for a in str(den)]
x.sort()
x1,x2= x
sden = x1+x2
#-----------------------------------------

if x1 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if x1 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if x1 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if x1 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if x1 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if x1 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if x1 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if x1 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if x1 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#-----------------------------------------

if x2 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if x2 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if x2 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if x2 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if x2 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if x2 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if x2 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if x2 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if x2 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#--------------------------------------------
    

print('Месяц:')
mes = input()
xx2 = [int(a) for a in str(mes)]
x.sort()
y1,y2= xx2
smes = y1+y2

#-----------------------------------------

if y1 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if y1 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if y1 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if y1 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if y1 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if y1 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if y1 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if y1 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if y1 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#-----------------------------------------

if y2 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if y2 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if y2 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if y2 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if y2 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if y2 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if y2 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if y2 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if y2 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#--------------------------------------------
    
print('Год:')
god = input()
x3 = [int(a) for a in str(god)]
x.sort()
z1,z2,z3,z4 = x3
sgod = z1+z2+z3+z4

#-----------------------------------------

if z1 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if z1 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if z1 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if z1 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if z1 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if z1 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if z1 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if z1 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if z1 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#-----------------------------------------

if z2 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if z2 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if z2 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if z2 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if z2 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if z2 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if z2 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if z2 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if z2 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#--------------------------------------------
#-----------------------------------------

if z3 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if z3 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if z3 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if z3 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if z3 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if z3 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if z3 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if z3 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if z3 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#-----------------------------------------

if z4 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if z4 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if z4 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if z4 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if z4 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if z4 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if z4 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if z4 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if z4 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#--------------------------------------------
    
h1 = sden+smes+sgod
hh1 = h1


if h1 < 10:
        h2 = h1
else:
    h2 = [int(a) for a in str(hh1)]
    x.sort()
    ph1,ph2= h2
    h2 = ph1+ph2

if h2 < 10:
        q2 = h2
        q1 = 0
else:
    qq1 = h2
    hq2 = [int(a) for a in str(qq1)]
    x.sort()
    q1,q2= hq2
    h2 = q1+q2
    
if h1 < 10:
        m2 = h1
        m1 = 0
else:
    mm1 = h1
    hm2 = [int(a) for a in str(mm1)]
    x.sort()
    m1,m2= hm2
    h2 = m1+m2

if x1 < 1:
    rh3 = dva*x2
    h3 = h1-rh3
else:
    rh3 = dva*x1
    h3 = h1-rh3


if h3 < 0:
    h3 = h3 * minus

if h3 < 10:
    h4 = h3
else:
    hh3 = h3
    hh3 = [int(a) for a in str(hh3)]
    x.sort()
    pph1,pph2= hh3
    h4 = pph1+pph2
    
if h3 < 10:
    pk1 = h3
    pk2 = 0
else:
    hhh3 = h3
    hhh3 = [int(a) for a in str(hhh3)]
    x.sort()
    pk1,pk2= hhh3
    kh4 = pk1+pk2

if h4 < 10:
        b1 = h4
        b2 = 0
else:
    hhh4 = h4
    hhh4 = [int(a) for a in str(hhh4)]
    x.sort()
    b1, b2 = hhh4
    kh4 = b1+b2

#-------------------------------------------- 
if pk2 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if pk2 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if pk2 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if pk2 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if pk2 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if pk2 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if pk2 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if pk2 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if pk2 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#--------------------------------------------

if pk1 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if pk1 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if pk1 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if pk1 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if pk1 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if pk1 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if pk1 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if pk1 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if pk1 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#-------------------------------------------- 
if b2 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if b2 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if b2 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if b2 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if b2 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if b2 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if b2 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if b2 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if b2 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#--------------------------------------------

if b1 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if b1 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if b1 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if b1 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if b1 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if b1 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if b1 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if b1 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if b1 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#-------------------------------------------- 
if m2 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if m2 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if m2 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if m2 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if m2 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if m2 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if m2 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if m2 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if m2 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#--------------------------------------------

if m1 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if m1 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if m1 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if m1 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if m1 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if m1 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if m1 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if m1 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if m1 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#-------------------------------------------- 
if q2 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if q2 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if q2 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if q2 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if q2 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if q2 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if q2 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if q2 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if q2 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'
#--------------------------------------------

if q1 == 1:
    a1 = a1 + '1'   

if q1 == 2:
    a2 = a2 + '2'   

if q1 == 3:
    a3 = a3 + '3'
    
if q1 == 4:
    a4 = a4 + '4'   

if q1 == 5:
    a5 = a5 + '5'   

if q1 == 6:
    a6 = a6 + '6'
    
if q1 == 7:
    a7 = a7 + '7'   

if q1 == 8:
    a8 = a8 + '8'   

if q1 == 9:
    a9 = a9 + '9'

if a1 == '':
    a1 = '---'
if a2 == '':
    a2 = '---'
if a3 == '':
    a3 = '---'
if a4 == '':
    a4 = '---'
if a5 == '':
    a5 = '---'
if a6 == '':
    a6 = '---'
if a7 == '':
    a7 = '---'
if a8 == '':
    a8 = '---'
if a9 == '':
    a9 = '---'
    
print('----------------')
print('|', a1, '|', a4, '|', a7, '|')
print('|', a2, '|', a5, '|', a8, '|')
print('|', a3, '|', a6, '|', a9, '|')
print('----------------')


print(h1,h2,'.',h3,h4)
```

Comment: Что делает программа?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Везде `x.sort()`.

Comment: Как? Начать уже изучать основы! Прочитать хотя бы любую книгу по python. Хотя бы ПОЛОВИНУ.

Comment: Феноменальный бред. Задача в чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Врятли кто-то остаться переписывать Ваше творчество, но могу дать пару советов:

1. Используйте списки. Это первое что бросается в глаза. a1,a2,…,a9 - замените одним списком и обращайтесь по индексу вместо цифры в название переменной.
2. Замените ваши многочисленные if на логичное математическое действие. Вы проверяете: если х1 = 1, то делаете что-то. Но ведь можно просто a[1] += x[1], если реализовать переменные как списки.
   Не особо понимаю зачем Вам тут конструкция if. Если она Вам действительно необходима, то используйте elif.
3. Кажется, это не похоже на какой либо проект. Скорее задача. Стоит ли это упрощать, если оно работает? А вообще советую подучить базовые вещи в python.